# Make a div's width equal to the width of the image it contains

Tags: html, css

another newbie question here. Learning CSS. I am trying to do something that I thought would be very simple, but have not managed to find the way to do it, or a suitable answer to the question.

I have a simple project with a header, some content and a footer. The content has a div with a white border and an image inside it. I would like the div to be as wide as the image and no wider. I have provisionally set the width to 430px, but I would like to know the code to set the width to whatever the width of the image is.

[image]

Code

html

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#container {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
}

#imagewrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid white;
  width: 430px;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="header"> </div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="imagewrap">
    <img src="Images/01Folder/Image.jpg" height="100%" id="front" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"> </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Add `display: inline-block;` to your `.imagewrap` without setting it's width.

```
.imagewrap {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

If you want a div with an image to be centered, add another div around them with:

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

But do you really need that `div` around an image? The border might be added to an image itself without additional `div`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a border on the image, add it there

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#container {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
}

#imagewrap {
  position: relative;
  /*border: 1px solid white;
  width: 430px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;*/
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  text-align: center; /*center image horizontally*/
}

#imagewrap img {
  border: 1px solid white;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"> </div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="imagewrap">
    <img src="https://unsplash.it/100/100" height="100%" id="front" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fidde:
https://jsfiddle.net/56myv9g2/1/

```
#imagewrap img{
  display:block;
}

#imagewrap{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#container {
  height: 80%;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align:center;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Also, you could just give the border to the image tag all along without the div

Answer (score 0):

If you set display: inline-block, then you need to add `text-align: center` to container

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  height: 100vh;
}

#header {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

#container {
  text-align: center;
  height: 80%;
  width: 100vw;
  background-color: red;
}

#imagewrap{
    position: relative;
 border: 1px solid white;
 width: 430px;
 display: inline-block;
 top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
    <div id="header"> </div>
<div id="container">
  <div id="imagewrap">
    <img src="Images/01Folder/Image.jpg" height="100%" id="front" />
  </div>
</div>
<div id="footer"> </div>
```